# Product measure and its marginals

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have this question that's bothering me. The answer (I think) should be trivial but I am new in measure theory.

Let $m$ be Radon measure on a compact product space $\Omega=X\times X$ such that $m$ is symmetric (I guess this means that $m(dx,dy)=m(dy,dx)$ and let $\lambda$ be a symmetric strictly positive function $\lambda:X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The question is the following: does it always exist a measure $\mu$ defined on $X$ such that$$\mu(dx)\mu(dy)= c\frac{m(dx,dy)}{\lambda(x,y)},$$ where $c$ is a positive constant?
How do you find it? Is it possible to say that it is a probability measure?

My immediate answer would be yes and $$\mu(dx)=\int \frac{m(\cdot,dy)}{\lambda(x,y)}$$
and it is a probability measure just because it can be rescalated (being $X$ a compact set)

Am I wrong? If so, can you give me a counterexample?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $X=[0,1]$, $m$ be the uniform distribution on the diagonal $D=\{(x,x)\mid x\in [0,1]\}$, and let $\lambda$ have the constant value $1$. The question then reduces to whether the uniform distribution on the diagonal is proportional to a product measure.  It is not. Indeed, the marginal distributions of $m$ are the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, but the corresponding product measure assigns measure zero to the diagonal.

Comment: Okay got it I think :). Thanks!

And, just for my curiosity, what if $m$ was absolutely continuous wrt to e.g the Lebesgue Measure. 

If $m(dx,dy)=f(x,y)dx dy$ then it is true, right?

Comment: If moreover $f>0$

Comment: You will always have the problem that there are many symmetric measures whose marginals are Lebesgue measure, even if they are absolutely continuous.